# Understanding selective receives in Erlang

Tags: erlang, timeout

I am reading [`LYAE`](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing#time-out)  chapter on timeouts and i can't wrap my head about what happens in the following scenario:

```
important() ->
   receive
     {Priority, Message} when Priority > 10 ->
         [Message | important()]
   after 0 ->
     normal()
   end.

normal() ->
   receive
     {_, Message} ->
         [Message | normal()]
   after 0 ->
         []
    end.

1> c(multiproc).
{ok,multiproc}
2> self() ! {15, high}, self() ! {7, low}, self() ! {1, low}, self() ! {17, high}.      
{17,high}
3> multiproc:important().
[high,high,low,low]
```

I do not understand the following:

1. Saying `after 0` its like using `,` from what i understand, it happens **EVEN** if the message matches in the `receive` clause?
2. After reading the first  message we have `[15, important()]`, which at the second iteration will call `normal` so we have one one hand  `[15, important() --3-rd call]` and  `[7,normal() -fourth call]`.
   So how in the end somehow we end up with two lists that get concatenated.
3. After reading the first 2 messages we have :

`important`  with `[15]` 
`normal`(first call) with `[7]`

Now `normal()` (first call) is already waiting for a new message ,and `important` now will make a second call to `normal()` so now in the second call won't we have `[1]` ?

I do not understand how do the `[7]` and `[1]` get merged since they are from separate calls to `normal()`.

I understand for `important()` since the result gets placed at the end of the list `[Message,important()]`.But that is not the case for `normal()` since it gets called by `important` and everytime it should create a new list.

[image]

**P.S** I have added a picture , to further explain my dilemma.I think i understand now that at the end the 2 branches will return their result into `[7,15]` but i still do not understand in what order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `receive`, we'll end up *either* in one of the matching clauses or in the `after` clause.  That is, the `after` clause will only be evaluated if there is no matching message within the timeout.  This is different from how `after` behaves in a `try`/`catch`, where it will be evaluated unconditionally.

---

These two functions follow a common Erlang pattern: building a list through recursive calls - the selective `receive` doesn't really matter here.  Note that this expression:

```
[Message | important()]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[Message] ++ important()
```

That is, we're creating a list whose first element is the message we received, and whose tail consists of whatever the recursive call returns.  The result is that we get a list of messages received, one after another.  The fact that at some point we switch to calling `normal()` instead of `important()` doesn't change that - we're still building the list one element at a time.

Step by step:

1. We call `multiproc:important()` from the shell
2. `important` receives `{15, high}`, we're now evaluating `[high] ++ important()`
3. The recursive call to `important` ignores `{7, low}` because it doesn't match, but receives `{17, high}` which does.  We're now evaluating `[high] ++ [high] ++ important()`
4. The second recursive call to `important` doesn't see any matching message and goes into the `after` clause.  We're now evaluating `[high] ++ [high] ++ normal()`
5. The call to `normal` receives `{7, low}`, we're now evaluating `[high] ++ [high] ++ [low] ++ normal()`
6. The recursive call to `normal` receives `{1, low}`, we're now evaluating `[high] ++ [high] ++ [low] ++ [low] ++ normal()`
7. The second recursive call to `normal` doesn't see any matching message and returns `[]` without making a recursive call.  We now have `[high] ++ [high] ++ [low] ++ [low] ++ []`, which is equal to `[high, high, low, low]`.

Comment: I have added a picture.

Comment: Right, seems like the confusion is that we ignore `{7, low}` as long as there are messages with higher priority in the message queue. That is, since we're doing a selective receive, we can receive messages out of order, and leave non-matching messages in the queue for later.

Comment: So you say that the `after` clause does not get called at all until all messages from the queue that can match have been scanned ? Does it not resolve all messages from the first passing ? Lets say it reaches message nr 2 which is `7` it just ignores it **AND** it does not dispatch it to `normal` until it reaches the end of the queue ? I was thinking every message is either put in the result or else `after` clause is called **ON THE FIRST PASSING** !

Comment: That is right. The queue contains `{7,low}, {1,low}, {17,high}`, but only the last message matches `{Priority, Message} when Priority > 10`, so it picks that one. Only when there are no matching messages does it go into `after`.

Comment: Oh i see now ....thank you very much for explaining me sir. So then since both the call to `normal` and the one to `important` share the same `mailbox` the `after` clause deals with the rest of messages.

Answer (score 2):

> Saying after 0 its like using , from what i understand, it happens
>   EVEN if the message matches in the receive clause?

Wrong.  If a message matches, then the `after` is skipped.

> After reading the first message we have [15, important()],

Wrong.  `[15 | important()]` is not the same as `[15, important()]`.  And 15 is the `Priority`--not the `Message`, yet it's the `Message`, e.g. `high`, that gets inserted into the list.

> somehow we end up with two lists that get concatenated.

Wrong.  The following messages are in the mailbox:

```
{15, high} 
{7, low}
{1, low}
{17, high}
```

1st important() call:

```
{15, high} matches the important() receive
return value: [high | important()]
```

Now erlang needs to call `important() again` and substitute the return value into `[high | important()]`.

The following messages are in the mailbox:

```
{7, low}
{1, low}
{17, high}
```

2nd important() call:

```
{7, low} doesn't match the important() receive
{1, low} doesn't match the important() receive
{17, high} matches the important() receive

return value: [high | important()]
```

Substituting into the result  of the 1st important return value:

```
          [high | important()] -- 2nd important() return value
            |
            V           
[high | important()] --  1st important() return value
```

gives you:

```
[high | [high | important()] ]
```

Now, erlang has to call `important()` a 3rd time and substitute the return value of the 3rd call into that result.

The following messages are in the mailbox:

```
{7, low}
{1, low}
```

3rd important() call:

```
{7, low} doesn't match the important() receive
{1, low} doesn't match the important() receive

So, the after executes immediately--because the timeout is 0.
return value: normal().
```

Replacing important() in the result `[high | [high | important()] ]` with `normal()` gives you:

```
[high | [high | normal()] ]
```

Now erlang has to evaluate `normal()` and substitute its return value into that result.

1st normal() call:

```
 {7, low} matches the normal() receive
 return value:  [low | normal()]
```

Doing the substitution:

```
             [low | normal()]
                   |
                   V
[high | [high | normal()] ]
```

gives:

```
[high | [high | [low | normal()] ] ]
```

The following messages are in the mailbox:

```
{1, low}
```

2nd normal() call:

```
{1, low} matches the normal() receive
return value: [low | normal()]
```

Doing the substitution:

```
                        [low | normal()]
                          |
                          V
[high | [high | [low | normal()] ] ]
```

produces:

```
[high | [high | [low | [low | normal()] ] ] ]
```

The following messages are in the mailbox:

```
 <none>
```

3rd normal call:

```
The after executes immediately because the timeout is 0.
return value:  []
```

Substituting:

```
                                []
                                |
                                V
 [high | [high | [low | [low | normal() ] ] ] ]
```

gives:

```
 [high | [high | [low | [low | [] ] ] ] ].
```

What is that mess??!

```
7> [high | [high | [low | [low | [] ] ] ] ].
[high,high,low,low]
```

In erlang, lists are defined recursively using the cons operator, `|`, and nested sub lists.  Here are some other examples:

```
8> [1 | [2 | [] ]].
[1,2]
```

The thing on the right hand side of the `|` (cons operator) has to be a list.  Erlang syntax also allows you to write this:

```
10> [1, 2, 3 | [4, 5]].
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Once again, the thing on the right of the `|` operator has to be a list, but you can write comma separated values on the left hand side.

Comment: Sorry i was confused with the Haskell cons operator.However when you use `after TIMEOUT` it means it already reached the end of the mailbox and waits `TIMEOUT` for a message matching the pattern to show up right ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, *it already reached the end of the mailbox.* -- Hmm...I don't know.  It could be that the timer starts before any messages are checked.  I don't know if erlang guarantees that the after clause will start executing in timeout milliseconds, or whether the wait could actually be many multiples of the timeout value.